# update_option working but Fields showing empty

Tags: php, wordpress, acfpro

I have created option in Theme Setting Option Page and updated using

`update_option('subscription_token', '1234');`

Now When using `get_option('subscription_token');` I can get the value 1234.

But the issue is on admin panel the fields still shows empty

For creating option I used ACF PRO

Comment: Both update_option and get_option are native WP functions, they have nothing to do with ACF.

Comment: @CBroe I agreed I just mentioned that for creating option I used ACF

Comment: ACF adds a little of its own magic to the default WP meta mechanism, I am not sure if it is supposed to work this way. Try and use https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/ to set the field value, and see what happens then. (You have to explicitly specify `'option'` or `'options'` as the post id parameter in this case.)